# How do I retrieve a success message in Magento?

Tags: magento

How do I retrieve a success message in Magento?

```
Array
(
    [core] => Array
        (
            [_session_validator_data] => Array
                (
                    [remote_addr] => 192.168.151.102
                    [http_via] => 
                    [http_x_forwarded_for] => 
                    [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
                )

            [session_hosts] => Array
                (
                    [technova2] => 1
                )

            [messages] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection Object
                (
                    [_messages:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_lastAddedMessage:protected] => Mage_Core_Model_Message_Success Object
                        (
                            [_type:protected] => success
                            [_code:protected] => Your review has been accepted for moderation
                            [_class:protected] => 
                            [_method:protected] => 
                            [_identifier:protected] => 
                            [_isSticky:protected] => 
                        )

                )

            [just_voted_poll] => 
            [visitor_data] => Array
                (
                    [] => 
                    [server_addr] => -1062692990
                    [remote_addr] => -1062693018
                    [http_secure] => 
                    [http_host] => technova2
                    [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.70 Safari/533.4
                    [http_accept_language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
                    [http_accept_charset] => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
                    [request_uri] => /~rahuls/sextoys/index.php/review/product/list/id/169/
                    [session_id] => 21bq2vtkup5m1gtghknlu1tit42c6dup
                    [http_referer] => http://technova2/~rahuls/sextoys/index.php/review/product/list/id/169/
                    [first_visit_at] => 2010-06-16 05:49:56
                    [is_new_visitor] => 
                    [last_visit_at] => 2010-06-16 06:00:00
                    [visitor_id] => 935
                    [last_url_id] => 23558
                )

            [last_url] => http://technova2/~rahuls/sextoys/index.php/review/product/list/id/169/
        )     
)
```

After posting the review I want to display the message: "Your review has been accepted for moderation". It appears in the $_SESSION array, but how do I fetch it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please mark this question as solved by choosing an answer as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It is a combination of all your answers.  This works for me from just about any block:

```
    //A Success Message
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess("Your cart has been updated successfully!");

    //A Error Message
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("Your cart has been updated successfully!");

    //A Info Message (See link below)
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice("This is just a FYI message...");

    //These two lines are required to get it to work
    session_write_close(); //THIS LINE IS VERY IMPORTANT!
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

Credit due to:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/40324/ (Where I posted the answer)

and

http://www.deepcodeonline.com/blog/magento/how-to-display-error-success-and-notice-messages-in-magento/

Answer (score 9):

The following code works for me:

1. set message the controller:

   ```php
   Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
       ->addSuccess(Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Data saved.'));
   ```
2. init message in the controller where you want to retrieve the
   message:

   ```php
   $this->loadLayout();
   $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
   $this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
   $this->renderLayout();`
   ```
3. Retrieve the message in your template (`.phtml`) file:

   ```php
   echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
   ```

Comment: i had to use $this->initLayoutMessages('checkout/session'); in my controller as i was looking to pull out the default "X was added to your shopping cart." message.  basically find where your message is getting stored to and put that in the initLayoutMessages call.

Comment: this is the most succinct explanation i could find of how Magento messages work. For others finding this, other common mesage types include checkout/session and core/session. Extensions tend to put messages in random locations so its sometimes easier to initialise all messages then pull them out one by one until you are getting the messages you want

Answer (score 7):

```
$messages = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true);
foreach($messages->getItems() as $message)
{
   // Do something   
   $message->getText();
}
```

Comment: don't forget to change the model to your needs: `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')`

Answer (score 5):

It seems that what you are requesting already exists in Magento. Once the user has posted a review about a product, the "Your review has been accepted for moderation" message appears by default as stated in app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php at line 188 (Magento 1.4.0.1)

Anyway, if you want to display messages (notice, success, error, warning) just use, for instance in case of a success message:

```
<?php
$message = $this->__('Your success message here');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess($message);
?>
```

The message will be store in the session and automatically appear on the frontend as long as the template file of the page has the $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() code which is the case in all default phtml pages shipped with Magento. So you don't really have to bother.

Of course, in the above example, you can change

```
addSuccess($message)
```

by
`addError($message)` or `addWarning($message)` or `addNotice($message)` depending of the kind of info your want to display.

Answer (score 3):

Since the message is stored in the `core` sub-array, you'll use the Magento core message block to retrieve it. In your layout, you should be able to see this line (in page.xml):

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
```

This means that the page calls the message block and retrieves messages from that core array. Then, in your layouts, you should be able to see the line that actually invokes the output:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
```

This actually echos the normal message blocks for any messages in the session. If you cannot find those blocks, add them in. If you need to get the message in a different context (this may interfere with other site operation), try this in a phtml file:

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/messages')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you want to retrieve a success message from a catalog session:

Then you had to retrieve messages from session as follows:

```
$messages = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->getMessages(false);
```

Putting `false` won't clear your messages collection from session. If you want to clear all messages after retrieving use `true` instead.

The `$messages` is of `Mage_Core_Model_Message_Collection` type. You can retrieve your needed type of messages from it by:

```
$successMessages = $messages->getItemsByType(Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS);
```

You can loop through those messages by:

```
foreach ($successMessages as $message) {
   //do whatever you like
}
```

Comment: Works. Be sure to get the correct session object, I needed `('customer/session')`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the below block in page.xml

I used the below two lines in my code for success message but no success.

getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
getLayout()->createBlock('core/messages')->toHtml(); ?>