# Magento get session messages

Tags: magento

I am trying to access Magento's current session's messages (ones written by addError).

I am doing this from inside of the Cart model.

`$smessages = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getMessages(true);`

Returns an array of all messages correctly.

However, when I try to "foreach" through $smessages, I get nothing. The idea is to then use getText() within the loop to get each individual message.

```
foreach ($smessages as $smessage) {
  Mage::log($smessage);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you want to use the "default" output provided by magento check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5878352/574881

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out!

```
 $smessages = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getMessages()->getItems();
 $output = NULL;
 foreach ($smessages as $smessage) {
      $output .= $smessage->getText();
 }
```

Comment: How do I detect if there are no messages set? (empty array)

Comment: Will not work in some cases. For example, wrong user credentials on login. Use the singleton of Mage_Core_Block_Messages instead.